# How to implement http2 (h2) in CentOs Server with Apache 2.4.23?

Tags: apache, rpm, http2, virtualmin, epel

I tried to install apache-2.4.23 which supports http2 in CentOS7 x64 server. But no rpm repo has supported it yet, so I built from source and installed and was installed to /usr/local/apache2. But since, I am using virtualmin5.0.4 I need it to be compatible with it. So, how could I install it in the locations as it would install if installed from repo such as EPEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try getting the source RPM from Fedora and doing `rpmbuild --rebuild apache.src.rpm`. Then you can update the RPMs you have and not have a hybrid of RPM-based installs and hand-installed files. Other RPMs will then know you have it installed as well as being in the default locations.

Comment: Can you get me link to get apache.src.rpm file for the version 2.4.23?@aaron-d-marasco

Comment: I am now getting this error. Failed build dependencies:
        apr-devel >= 1.5.0 is needed by httpd-2.4.23-4.el7.centos.x86_64

Comment: Welcome to dependency hell when you use CentOS... you need to build the `apr` libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the install location as a `--prefix` option to the configure script.